# Filter or search Trello cards by created user

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I'm trying to work out a way to find cards that have been created by a specific person - not necessarily tagged as a member or added a comment.

I've looked through the filters and can't see anything so wondered if someone know a way to find these cards.